Jhipster API Gateway request is getting 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Using jhipster-generate, I have created a gateway application which acts as an Angular frontend running on localhost:8090 and I have a microservice application already running with endpoints setup on localhost:8082.
I have setup application.yml configurations of Spring Cloud Gateway:
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: service
          uri: http://localhost:8082
          predicates:
            - Path=/service/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/service/(?<segment>.*), /${segment}

and of Jhipster API Gateway:
jhipster:
  gateway:
    authorized-microservices-endpoints:
      service: /service/**

Then I am sending a POST request from the frontend to the URL: http://localhost:8090/service/api/get-permission but getting 405 Method Not Allowed everytime.
I tried sending a GET request to the same URL, I get 200 OK but the request is not routed to localhost:8082 but returns the main HTML file of the Angular application. How can I troubleshoot this gateway mechanism?
N.b: I am not using any service discovery such as Eureka or Consul

please check /get-permission api works correctly from its app.

@amirrad yes it works. can access it from other applications
